# iPhone: Performances Differences Between NSURLRequestCachePolicy Settings

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, nsurlcache

When using [NSURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequestCachePolicy) on the iPhone, what are the real world performance differences between the various [NSURLRequestCachePolicy](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequestCachePolicy) settings? I am specifically interested in the cache policy's effect on the the user's perception of the speed at which UIWebView pages display.

I have been using the default `NSURLRequestCachePolicy` but I think that perhaps NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData could be best for most cases especially when going back to a previous page.

If you've used various cache policies under real-world conditions, which policy proved optimum in a particular circumstance?  What policy provides the best overall performance over the three different types of iPhone connections, wi-fi, 3G and Edge? Does the cache policy even have any significant effect on the user's perception of page loading speed or should I be looking elsewhere to optimize UIWebView's display time?

### Update:

There seems to be a consensus that UIWebView appears to ignore the cache settings on any NSURLRequest given it. I do not have complete confidence that this is the final answer but barring the time to do some extensive testing, I cannot gainsay it. Therefore, I am accepting the highest rated answer. However, I would advise that you take the answers with a grain of salt if the matter is of importance to your project. -- TechZen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this will make any difference on your UIWebView loading times. UIWebView is built on WebKit, and they're not using `NSURLConnection` internally (they are at a much lower level and use `CFNetwork` directly).

This is probably not what you want to hear, but probably the best way to speed up UIWebView loading time is to not use a UIWebView. Rendering web pages is pretty CPU-intensive. In fact, MobileSafari is actually mostly CPU-bound, not network-bound -- notice how long it takes it to fill in that checkerboard pattern when scrolling, for example. For really fast, quickly loading content, it's best to create a native interface in Cocoa.

Comment: Are you certain about this? The `-[UIWebView loadRequest]` does accept a `NSURLRequest` which does have a cache policy attached. Is that just ignored? Why use a request if it is not used to managed the connection? I do not have the time to create a webview from scratch so I need to optimize this one.

Comment: You're asking for implementation details about Apple frameworks that I don't know about. The easiest way to figure out if it affects perceived performance is to do your own testing.

Comment: Looks like I will have to but such testing is difficult because you can only sample a small number of pages. It's hard to get good data. I  had hoped someone knew the details but I suppose it's an esoteric question.

Answer (score 2):

I a few hours for a project trying to get a `UIWebView` to cache pages I was loading. It proved impossible from the application side without storing the files locally. It seems that `UIWebView` ignores the `NSURLRequestCachePolicy` completely.

[Yahoo! has some info](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2008/02/06/iphone-cacheability/) on the iPhone's caching behaviour.

Comment: The Yahoo! page is interesting but it is two years old. I'm not sure how relevant it is.

Comment: Good point. At very least, newer hardware probably caches more.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a grep on the WebKit sources, and didn't find any use of the `-[NSURLRequest cachePolicy]`.