# iOS UIWebView failing to cache a response

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, caching, uiwebview

I am attempting to cache a webpage within a UIWebView using `NSURLRequestCachePolicy` `UseProtocolCachePolicy` - however, I can validate from my network monitor that the UIWebView is carrying out a full reload on every request and never loading the stored cache.

There is an older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261206/iphone-performances-differences-between-nsurlrequestcachepolicy-settings) claiming that UIWebView ignores cache settings on any NSURLRequest given to it. However, this seems inconclusive at best.

Below are the response headers from the server - the most pertinent is `Cache-Control: no-cache`, which requires clients to revlidate the cache before rendering; this appears acceptable as Apple's default caching behavior (shown below) seems to account for this.

***Update***

Updating the caching policy to `ReturnCacheDataElseLoad` will cause the cache to be loaded - so it looks like UIWebview can indeed cache responses; however, this functionality returns a cache no matter how old it is and that is far from desired.

**Swift Code**

```
let url = "http://web.page.com"
let requestURL = NSURL(string: url)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 15.0)

webView.loadRequest(request)
```

**Server Response Headers**

```
Accept-Ranges → bytes
Cache-Control → no-cache
Content-Encoding → gzip
Content-Length → 54794
Content-Type → text/html
Date → Tue, 14 Jul 2015 18:50:22 GMT
ETag → "807677b3872d01:0"
Last-Modified → Wed, 08 Apr 2015 14:31:29 GMT
Pragma → no-cache
Proxy-Connection → Keep-alive
Server → Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Vary → Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By → ASP.NET
X-Robots-Tag → noarchive
```

**Apple's Default Caching Protocol**

[image]